# How to see which analytic table is bound to the dashboard in wso2 das

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

In **WSO2 DAS**, I have created a Dashboard conatining a Gadget to display the analytic table as a bar chart. But when I try to get the json of the Dashboard and the gadget, It does not contain any inform on which analytic table/stream is bound with the gadget.

Please let me know on how to find out which analytic table is bound to the gadget in the dashboard.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I assume that you have created gadgets using "Gadget Wizard" (if not please let me know)

Then the analytic table name can be found in the following configuration file.

```
gadget_folder/js/gadgetconf.js
```

In above configuration file, there will be an attribute called 'datasource' and that points to the actual analytics table.

Thanks,

Upul

Comment: Thanks Upul, Your reply solved my problem. Found what I was looking for.